# Surfaces of Constant Gaussian Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm preparing for an exam and I would like to know what are some examples of surfaces with constant Gaussian curvature such as surfaces with $k=0, \pm1$

Comment: Have you computed many examples yourself? There are many common surfaces which have constant Gauss curvature, namely those you've listed in particular. In fact, there's a beautiful theorem that says that any compact surface with constant Gauss curvature $K > 0$ is part of a sphere of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$. I'll post a more detailed answer below once you update.

Comment: May be you meant "locally isometric to", but not "part of ", which implies rigidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: try to compute the Gaussian curvature for the following objects (embedded) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using parametrization:

- Plane, cylinder, cone(away from the vertex)
- Sphere
- Tractrix, tractricoid